# Help on wiring diagram for baseboard heaters

Tags: electrical

Can I wire in parallel 2 wall thermostats to 2 separate baseboard heaters along with another baseboard heater with a thermostat already installed in the heater?

I have drawn up a diagram of what I'm trying to do but I need help in knowing what wires to connect and where

This is for a 200 amp service with 20 amp double pole breaker and a double pole honeywell therostats with 750 watt baseboard heater per thermostat.

Can someone connect the letters on my diagram if it's possible to do this?

Thank you. [image]

Comment: I think you're gonna need more cables.

Comment: Do you need room 2 and room 3 to be completely independent? I don't think you want room 3 on only when room 2 is on.

Comment: ye, in all 3 rooms want the heaters are on independently

Comment: Instead of a cable from room 2 heater to room 3 heater, you need a cable from room 2 thermostat to room 3 heater. If necessary this cable could follow the physical path via room 2 heater.

Comment: yes independently

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it with the cables as shown! You need a new cable from before  the second thermostat and the third heater. Like so:
[image]

Not shown are green/bare ground wires connecting the grounds on **everything**.

Because in the US, 240 volts is two opposite leg hots, red and black wire are interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you so much for showing how to connect the wires and for pointing out where I had incorrectly ran to the last heater and it makes sense to me what you said. I didn't include the ground wire for simplicity but will connect them too. Much appreciated for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Thank you, you have been so helpful. 

Could you tell me the following?

1: I am limited to wall space and the only wall available to me is above a light switch. So would it be ok to if I put a thermostat above a light switch?

 2: can I put a thermostat on a wall with another thermostat adjacent behind it on same wall?

3: I just realized that the stat on the baseboard heater I got is a single pole stat... Can I still tie into the single pole even though the other two stats are double pole or should i get another heater with double pole installed?

Thanks

Comment: @fritz For #3, as long as the heater is rated for ~240 volts, it's fine, even if the thermostat is single-pole.

Comment: Thanks  @doxylover for your help. Appreciated your responses.